# Sencha touch reset store start param

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a store which is attached to a `List`. The list also uses the `ListPaging` plugin to enable pagination. After I call the `load` method (or event) of the store, the store loads the data into the list, sending requests to the following url -

```
http://localhost/mysite/nodelist.php?_dc=1359309895493
    &tids=1%2C4%2C2%2C5%2C67&page=1&start=0&limit=10
```

After scrolling down the list and pressing the `Load More...` (which is appended to the list by the plugin), the store sends another request to the same url but with different parameters, enabling pagination -

```
http://localhost/mysite/nodelist.php?_dc=1359310357419
    &tids=1%2C4%2C2%2C5%2C67&page=2&start=10&limit=10
```

Now I want to reset the value of the `start` and `page` parameter of the store. I tried to reset it by using the `setExtraParam` method on the proxy, but if I do that, then the control doesn't maintain the pagination - meaning that it doesn't automatically changes the `page` and `start` parameters when I press `Load More...`.

So  How do I do it?

Here is the sample code for my store -

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [
        'Ext.data.reader.Json',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax'
    ],

    config: {
        autoLoad: false,
        model: 'MyApp.model.MyModel',
        serverUrl: null,
        pageSize: 2,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            actionMethods: {
                read: 'GET'
            },
            url: null,
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        },
        listeners: {
            beforeload: function () {
                console.log('Before load');
            },
            load: function (store) {
                // console.log('load');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and this is the list view -

```
list = {
    xtype: 'list',
    cls: 'myList',
    flex: 12,
    itemTpl: '{title}',
    store: 'MyStore',
    plugins: [
        {
            xclass: 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
            autoPaging: false
        }
    ],
    listeners: {
        select: {
            scope: this,
            fn: this.onSelect
        },
        swipe: {
            scope: this,
            element: 'element',
            fn: this.onListSwipe
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From looking at the source, perhaps you are looking for the [currentPage](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-property-currentPage) config of the store?

When you load more recording using the ListPaging plugin, all it does is call `nextPage` in store which then calls `loadPage` using the `currentPage` config. If you reset the `currentPage` config back to 1 on your store, it will just assume the start is back to 0 and the page of course is 1.

Comment: Yup, it worked. I have added a method in my store which resets the paging by setting the `currentPage` property of the store to 1 (however, I think this should be a method in the sencha store too).